How are anabolic reactions different from addition reactions?
This may be a basic question, but I am struggling with the concept all the same. Anabolic reactions are described as using energy to "build complex molecules from simpler organic compounds (e.g., proteins from amino acids, carbohydrates from sugars, fats from fatty acids and glycerol)" (Britannica). Addition reactions have a very similar definition: they are described as reactions in which two or more substances combine and form a single substance. According to multiple sources, however, anabolic reactions are endothermic and addition reactions tend to be exothermic. I know forming bonds releases energy and so it makes sense that addition reactions would be exothermic, but why isn't it the same for anabolic reactions? Essentially, I am wondering why they are different reactions when they seem to have very similar definitions. Thanks!


Consider join or leave of atoms/parts of molecules to yield new molecules as one property of a chemical reaction (mass balance). 2) An other property of a chemical reaction is the energetic balance vs. the environment (hence terms like exothermic, endergonic, etc.). This accounts over all bounds broken vs all bounds newly established.  3) Instead of "combination reaction" (what is the reference for this one?), consider "addition" as reaction type (less molecules after the reaction, than prior). (Many organic reactions are either addition, elimination, substitution; or a pericyclic one.)


The term anabolic refers
to reactions that are part of an organism's anabolic metabolism, or anabolism. It does not tell you what type of chemical reaction it is. As suggested by Maurice, anabolic reactions are not necessarily two compounds added together to yield one, but they may be condensation reactions, dehydration reactions, reductions, etc. The umbrella term anabolism covers all sorts of reactions that generate the macromolecules that build up an organism. The opposite of anabolism is catabolism, when large molecules are broken down into smaller ones.

The anabolic reactions you mentioned in the original text are not addition reactions.
Each time a new bond is made by combining two amino acids, the reaction produces also water. Each time sugars are reacting to produce carbohydrates, water is also produced simultaneously. Each time a new bond is created when one fatty acid is reacting with glycerol, one molecule water is emitted. Your reactions are not addition reactions. They can be called condensation, but not addition. All your reactions are of the type : $$\ce{A + B -> C + D}$$ where A and B may be amino-acids, or sugars. or glycerol and a fatty acid. And here $\pu{D}$ is often $\ce{H2O}$. Addition reactions are different. They can be described by the general equation $$\ce{A + B -> C}$$
